# Plot the ATH of MACD since listed in the pine editor

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I want to have a trade setup which I will go long when MACD make new ATH, so are there any option to make an ATH Macd indicator?

I tried
 `highestmacd = highest(macd,5000)` but it's not working since each stock has different number of days listed in the market

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
var float highestmacd = na

firstmacd = not na(macd) and na(macd)[1]

if firstmacd
    highestmacd := macd
else
    if macd > highestmacd
        highestmacd := macd
```

Use `var` declared `highestmacd` to store the highest MACD found as the script progressed through the barset.

Being moving average based, initial macd values will be `na` until `bar_index` reaches at least the longest MA length. We can detect the first MACD value that isn't `na` by using the `na()` function and store that MACD value as the first `highestmacd`. There after we update the value each bar if it is higher.